# Pandas: Get rows with consecutive column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I need to go through a large pd and select consecutive rows with similar values in a column. i.e. in the pd below and selecting column x: I want to specify consecutive values in column x? Say if I want consecutive values of 3 and 5 only

```
col row x   y
1   1   1   1
5   7   3   0
2   2   2   2
6   3   3   8
9   2   3   4
5   3   3   9
4   9   4   4
5   5   5   1
3   7   5   2
6   6   6   6
5   8   6   2
3   7   6   0
```

The results output would be:

```
col row x   y   consecutive-count
6   3   3   8          1
9   2   3   4          1 
5   3   3   9          1
5   5   5   1          2
3   7   5   2          2
```

I tried

```
m = df['x'].eq(df['x'].shift())
df[m|m.shift(-1, fill_value=False)]
```

But that includes the consecutive 6 that I don't want.

I also tried:

```
df.query( 'x in [3,5]')
```

That prints every row where x has 3 or 5.

Comment: What should happen if you have other groups of 3 or 5?

Comment: Also, did you delete the other question? I cannot find it anymore (you should keep it, it was probably useful to others)

Comment: @mozway I accidentally deleted it. I have restored it.

Comment: @mozway I am keeping all consecutive 3s or 5ves.  so no single 3's or 5ves

Comment: have you tested my answer? Does it work as you want? If not, please provide a counter example with explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a group column for consecutive values, and filter by the group count and value of x:

```
# create unique ids for consecutive groups, then get group length:
group_num = (df.x.shift() != df.x).cumsum()
group_len = group_num.groupby(group_num).transform("count")

# filter main df:
df2 = df[(df.x.isin([3,5])) & (group_len > 1)]

# add new group num col
df2['consecutive-count'] = (df2.x != df2.x.shift()).cumsum()
```

output:

```
   col  row  x  y  consecutive-count
3    6    3  3  8                  1
4    9    2  3  4                  1
5    5    3  3  9                  1
7    5    5  5  1                  2
8    3    7  5  2                  2
```

Comment: this worked, any idea how to add another column that counts the consecutive 3s and 5vs ? Like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73327208/pandas-get-rows-with-consecutive-column-values#:~:text=col%20row%20x%20%20%20y%20%20%20consecutive%2Dcount%0A6%20%20%203%20%20%203%20%20%208%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%201%0A9%20%20%202%20%20%203%20%20%204%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%201%20%0A5%20%20%203%20%20%203%20%20%209%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%201%0A5%20%20%205%20%20%205%20%20%201%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%202%0A3%20%20%207%20%20%205%20%20%202%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%202

Comment: you just want a column that increments value at each group?

Comment: if so, you can just use the same trick with `cumcount()`

Comment: yes, I need a column that increments the value at each group. I cant seem to make it work with cumcount(). Any example please...

Comment: i already added the example above

Answer (score 2):

IIUC use masks for boolean indexing. Check for 3 or 5, and use a `cummax` and reverse `cummax` to ensure having the order:

```
m1 = df['x'].eq(3)
m2 = df['x'].eq(5)

out = df[(m1|m2)&(m1.cummax()&m2[::-1].cummax())]
```

Output:

```
   col  row  x  y
2    6    3  3  8
3    9    2  3  4
4    5    3  3  9
6    5    5  5  1
7    3    7  5  2
```